# FastCGI Process error when enable cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have:

windows Server 2003 - IIS 7.0 - PHP 5.2

Now I tried to install cURL. I get the `php_curl.dll` in the **php.ini** and have the right extension path. I also added the both needed dll-files to the **system32** directory.

Poorly as soon as I activate the `extension=php_curl.dll` line, I get an internal error 500 with `Fast-CGI cannot be loaded correctly`.

When I comment the `extension=php_curl.dll` line out, it works fine.

Any ideas?

I found this in the error log from windows events:

```
Fehlerhafte Anwendung php-cgi.exe, 
Version 5.2.13.13, 
Zeitstempel 0x4b853880, 
fehlerhaftes Modul php-cgi.exe, 
Version 5.2.13.13, 
Zeitstempel 0x4b853880, 
Ausnahmecode 0xc0000005, 
Fehleroffset 0x0000191a, 
Prozess-ID 0xf21c, 
Anwendungsstartzeit 01cb29beb76560b4.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing it from the command line (PHP that is).  My guess is the curl lib that you are referencing is either out of date, invalid or compiled for a different version of PHP...

Open `cmd.exe`, navigate to the php binary directory, type `php.exe -v`

Comment: How?................

Comment: open `cmd.exe`, navigate to the php binary directory, type `php.exe -v`